# Проблемы с пушем на гитхаб

Tags: git, github, terminal, git-push

При пуше на гитхаб выдает следующую ошибку

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing 
http://github.com/tomdwan/mm-tasks.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

в интернете нагугл что надо зайти в файл репы .git/config и заменить урл на

```
url=ssh://git@github.com/tomdwan/mm-tasks.git
```

В итоге тоже пушить не хочет, выдает

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: а у вас есть право записи в этот репозиторий?

Answer (score 0):

Вы скорее всего не добавили свой публичный ключ на github.

Либо добавьте его, либо измените `url` на `https://github.com/tomdwan/mm-tasks.git`.